# check if input number is within range of unsigned 16 bits number

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

hi I have this code in assembly x86

```
L1:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call writeString
    call readHex
    JO L1
```

I'm trying to check if the unsigned hexadecimal number that I input is larger than 16 bits,
so for example I inputted fffffffff, this will cause the overflow in ax but not eax, but read hex stored result back in to eax, so the JO instruction would not repeat the L1 loop, how do i check for only ax to get overflow flag to set?

thank in advance

Comment: `jo` would be for signed overflow anyway. Try `cmp eax, 0FFFFh` \ `jbe L1`

Comment: JO is actually for the overflow flag value

Answer (score 0):

The overflow would only work if you were doing ax to ax or eax to eax

You are doing eax to ax so a cmp is needed